# can I expect better than 60 milliseconds response time from google compute to google datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm measuring the latency between google cloud compute engine and google datastore.

I'm performing a simple lookup() using the python client library.

The google performance dashboard says that my requests are consuming around 18 milliseconds. I assume that this is a server side metric and not a round trip metric.

I have added some details to my research on github.

I could not find an answer to this specific question on stackoverflow so far:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/5#issuecomment-72590494

Comment: By performance dashboard, do you mean the App Engine Admin Console?

Comment: Never mind, I see you provided more information in the GitHub issue.

Answer (score 3):

While Cloud Datastore does not yet provide latency guarantees, the latencies you're seeing are in line with what we've measured.

The timing information you can see in the App Engine Admin Console is computed server-side so it will not reflect the full latency of the request.

We are working on a new serving stack that should substantially reduce this latency.

Comment: Thanks!

In these examples, the delay seems to be at the TCP level due to delayed ack's.

Is this service stack shared by all google cloud services?

I guess what I'm trying to ask is this the minimum latency that I can expect from all google cloud services until this is changed?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: I can't make a blanket statement about the latency you'll see with other services (I'd recommend checking their documentation if you have particular latency requirements). But this particular serving stack is only used by Cloud Datastore.

Comment: Note: This was as of v1beta2 - there has been significant performance improvements since then via v1beta3 and now v1, so latency numbers will be much better.

Comment: @DanMcGrath I'm using [google-cloud-java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java), am I correct in understanding that this library essentially uses v1beta3?  Do I have extra overhead of any sort by using google-cloud-java?